# How do you write a bash script function that is dynamic to the parameters passed?

Tags: bash

I have a bash function (slightly simplified for explaining)

```
copy_to() {
    cp $1 $2 $3
}
```

This works fine:

```
copy_to -f /demo/example1.xml new_demo/
```

But Let's say I want to copy all the xml files, the following code will have issues:

```
copy_to -f /demo/*.xml new_demo/
```

Obviously I could just write `cp -f /demo/*.xml new_demo/`, but is there anyway to get the copy_to function to work for a list of files (which passes more than just 3 parameters) as well as a single file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are `$@` and `$*` which contain a list of all parameters. You should use `$@`, because it works inside of double quotes. Else, file names containing spaces would break your code.

```
copy_to() {
    cp "$@"
}
```

If one of the parameters is special, you can use the `shift` command to remove it from the list of parameters, like so:

```
example() {
    destination="$1"
    shift
    echo "copying $@ to $destination"
}
```

`shift` removes the first parameter from the list, therefore you’ll have to save it in another location first. After calling `shift`, the contents of `$1` will be what was `$2`, `$2` will contain what was `$3` and so on. `$@` expands to all parameters (excluding those that were removed by `shift`).

Note that you cannot shift parameters off the *end* of your parameter list, only from the beginning.

Comment: Of course, you could grab the last element then unset it, which is basically the same as shifting off the end.

Comment: Although doing that is quite a bit more complicated. How would you do it? Is there even a POSIX-compatible way to do it? (Yes, I know the question says “bash”, but most people don’t know the difference, and writing for a single shell only is bad.)

Comment: In Bash, you can access all but the last parameter like this: `${@:0:$((${#@} - 1))}` (subtract 2 to omit the last two, etc.). Writing for a single shell only is not always bad - why have other shells if all you're going to use is the POSIX (or original Bourne) subset?

Comment: Correcting and simplifying my previous comment: `${@:1:$#-1}`

Answer (score 3):

If you need to iterate over the arguments:

```
f() {
    for arg
    do
        do_something $arg
    done
}
```

The `in $@` is implied in `for arg` (explicitly: `for arg in $@`).

Answer (score 2):

As Scytale said $@ and $* contain a list of all parameters. $# contains param count.

You can consider use [getopts command](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html) for parameter parsing.

Best regards